# Do event listeners need to be inside IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iife

I often see that many event listener codes are wrapped inside IIFE `(function(e){}())` I felt it is unnecessary to keep the event listeners inside IIFE. for example:

**Without IIFE**

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
    console.log("inside plain load");
});
```

**With IIFE**

```
(function(){
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
        console.log("inside wrapped load");
    });
}())
```

If we include above code together in a js file, on load event they execute only based on the order it was written.

I know that IIFE invoke itself, but what is the use of having event listeners inside it?, anyways it's gonna fire only if the event happens.

- Is there any need to wrap event listeners inside IIFE?
- Is event listeners inside IIFE is really a good practice?

Comment: There is no difference in those two sets of code you have listed. Reasons why you would do it is to declare variables, but keep them out of global scope. `(function(){ var foo;
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){ foo = true; }) }())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example there is no difference.

The main reason to use IIFE is to prevent leaking variables in the global scope.

```
(function(){
    let notLeakedVariable = 'something'
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
        console.log("inside wrapped load");
        console.log(notLeakedVariable)
    });
}())
```

Without IIFE you'll leak the variable in the global scope.

By wrapping your listener, you could even group multiple listeners and they'll share the same scope though closures.

```
(function(){
    let sharedVariable = 'something'
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
        console.log("inside wrapped load");
        // sharedVariable is accessible 
    });

    jQuery(selector).on("click", function(){
        // sharedVariable is accessible 
    });
}())
```

Comment: Though the other answers are relatively same, it explains better.

Answer (score 2):

You use IIFE because you want a local scope to isolate everything from the global scope.

```js
(function() {
  var count = 0;
  
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("hi", count++);
  });
}());
```

```html
hello world
```

In the above code, no one else in the world can touch `count`. Only the function that does the console.log can access it.  So `count` is not contaminating the global scope, and is also protected from the outside world.

Note that the IIFE is providing a local scope. Some JavaScript expert may call it a closure, but closure has nothing to do with it here. All you want here is a local scope.

The function that does `console.log`, is a closure.  It is a function that takes the scope chain and is able to access `count`. This is the behavior of a closure.

So this function has access to `count`, and nothing else does. So this IIFE provides a good way to write something self contained, not contaminate the outside world, and not let the outside world contaminate it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect the way the callback is bound, but there are a few reasons why you might see it.

1. If the JS file is loaded directly via  tag, then the IIFE will close-over any variables created in the IIFE, and they won't be visible on the global `window` object. For example, if you wrote `var x = 'foo'` in the IIFE, it won't be visible as `window.x`, but it would be without the IIFE.
2. Some functions return values that you don't want to expose. For example `jQuery(window).on(...)` actually returns something. You can't simply assign a variable in front of it and get it because of the IIFE.